# How is a Steam Power Plant designed?

Tags: turbines, power-engineering, steam

I asked this question at physics but i think this suits it more. I'd like to know few things about how does one design a Thermal Power Plant? There is something fundamentally lacking in my knowledge as I think there are a lot of parameters that I’m having trouble defining or estimating. I suppose this comes from difference between classroom studying and practical knowledge. So, let's talk about a small thermal plant of 1MW capacity. I have tried my best to be as clear as possible, but if some sentence is not making sense, I apologize in advance.

Starting with the steam turbine, I'm really struggling to find any specifications of that small size, while I know for sure that 1MW thermal power plants exists. And even when I do find the specifications, they mention only Temperature at which steam is to be fed and its Pressure. (Example: https://www.siemens.com/global/en/home/products/energy/power-generation/steam-turbines/d-r-steam-turbines.html) While these two are important and are the only parameters needed to find the enthalpy (h1), shouldn’t mass flow rate be included too? And what about the steam that will come out of turbine, only with that I’ll know what’s enthalpy at end (h2) and will be able to find its efficiency. Sometimes in specification they mention exhaust pressure without the temperature. How does that help? By multiplying the difference in enthalpies with mass flow rate ’ll get the power that I’m pumping in Turbine in form of steam. (correct me if I’m wrong here).

Once I understand the above, I’d like to know how the 1MW generation reacts to variable mass flow rate of constant temperature and pressure. As for the other components, I believe knowing the state of exhaust steam will help in deciding them. So, I may talk about them later.

If there are any free source books or videos available discussing the above then I’d be happy to go through it.

Comment: A good book is Engineering Thermodynamics Work and Heat Transfer by Rogers and Mayhew, but don't expect it to be free...